# NoSuchMethodException in Intellij in basic project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just started to learn Java and I want to use Intellij however I'm not able to run any project(even a simple Hello World). I always get this Exception.

[image]

Comment: `main` should be uncapitalized.

Comment: Please don't use images to display text. Type it in.

Comment: But what's wrong with images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow proper syntax for the main method . .

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   //Your code
}
```

You have used method name as Main change it to main it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the method name. It must be 'main' always because Java is case sensitive and JVM always looks for a 'main' method to run.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```